# unable to find css in index.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxoDV.png)I have a React app with node backend

I get this error:

> ```
> Failed to compile
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'
> ```

My index.js is as follows:

```
import "assets/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Comment: What are you doing to generate that error? It doesn't generally make sense to import CSS unless you are using a toolchain which handles them (such as Webpack with a CSS plugin for it). Do you have that? Are you trying to run your React program directly with Node instead of launching a dev server? You need to provide more detail.

Comment: i am adding a custom template i my application.when i compile the code using yarn dev, it gives me above error. pls checkk the project directory image in the question i have update dit

Comment: Can you please share the folder where your index.js is located? I can't see the index.js file in the image posted @allabtcoding

Comment: its in src folder

Answer (score 0):

In case of import, you must first go to the previous directory. For this you must use "./".

Try this if the file is in the same directory: './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'

if not, go to the correct directory using "../" instead of "./"

Comment: pls chk the question, i have updated it with an image

Answer (score 0):

It's a path related issue:

1. make sure the path is correct (if `assets` in the root do something like `/assetts/css ..`)
2. make sure the file `bootstrap.min.css` exists
3. make sure you don't uppercase or lowercase some letters